# Merge similar lines using regex in perl

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, merge

Hi I am in the process of sorting a file and i want to make it easier to read by merging similar lines together. The data is already sorted alpabetically based on the first word on each line. My program so far only reads in the lines to an array and prints it.

**Text file contains:**

```
Network ubuntu Jan  1 13:42:13 : <info>  DHCP: device eth5 state changed bound -> renew Network
Network ubuntu Jan  2 13:42:42 : <info>    prefix 24 (255.255.255.0) Network
Network ubuntu Jan  2 12:11:42 : <info>  DHCP: device eth5 state changed bound -> renew Network
testing ubuntu Jan  1 01:13:42 : DHCPACK of 192.168.233.129 from 192.168.233.254 testing
testing ubuntu Jan  2 13:54:42 : DHCPACK of 192.168.233.129 from 192.168.233.254 testing
testing ubuntu Jan  3 13:02:42 : DHCPACK of 192.168.233.129 from 192.168.233.254 testing
```

**My program:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

$FILE = '/computer/testfile.txt';
open(INFO, $FILE);

while($line = <INFO>){
    push(@array, $line);
}

print @array;
```

I want to use regex to merge any lines that are identicle, excluding the date/time stamp. The outcome is to contain the number of lines merged in brackets, followed by the earliest and latest date/time stamps. If there are no similar lines it ignores the line leaving it unchanged.

**Expected end result**

```
Network ubuntu Jan  2 13:42:42 : <info>    prefix 24 (255.255.255.0) Network
Network ubuntu (2) Jan  1 13:42:13-Jan  2 12:11:42: <info>  DHCP: device eth5 state changed bound -> renew Network
testing ubuntu (3) Jan  1 01:13:42-Jan  3 13:02:42 : DHCPACK of 192.168.233.129 from 192.168.233.254 testing
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Time::Piece](http://p3rl.org/Time::Piece) to parse the dates. Note that without year, you can't really sort the timestamps.

Just read the sorted file line by line. If the information is the same as on the previous line, accumulate the timestamp, otherwise output the previous accumulated information and start accumulating the new one.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Time::Piece;


sub output {
    my ($pre, $post, @timestamps) = @_;
    if (@timestamps > 1) {
        @timestamps = map $_->[0],                 # Use Schwartzian Transform to sort by timestamp.
                      sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
                      map [ $_, 'Time::Piece'->strptime($_, '%b %d %H:%M:%S') ],
                      @timestamps;
        print "$pre (", scalar @timestamps, ") ",
              $timestamps[0], '-', $timestamps[-1],
              $post, "\n";
    } else {
        print "$pre$timestamps[0]$post\n";
    }
}


my @last;
my @timestamps;
while (<>) {
    my ($pre, $timestamp, $post)
        = /(.*?) ([ADFJMNOS][aceopu][bcglnprtvy]\s+[0-9]+\s[0-9:]+) (.*)/x;

    if (@last and $pre eq $last[0] and $post eq $last[1]) {
        push @timestamps, $timestamp;

    } else {
        output(@last, @timestamps) if @timestamps;
        @last = ($pre, $post);
        @timestamps = ($timestamp);
    }
}
output(@last, @timestamps); # Don't forget to output the last batch.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Will this work if similar lines are a few lines apart? as my test data does not really have any similar lines next to each other more like 10-15 lines apart. Can regex be used for this?

Comment: @user3423572: No, it won't work. You can still use a regex, but you have to hash the common parts of the lines.